# ModX Evolution: Template Variable Conflict

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, placeholder, modx, modx-evolution

I'm writing a javascript plugin using instafeed.js. I'm having a problem with ModX Evolution because of this line of my code: 
`template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>'`

I'm pretty sure ModX is trying to associate {{link}} and {{image}} with Chunks that do not exist, causing my plugin to crash. Is there a way to tell ModX that {{link}} and {{image}} are not Chunks, but part of the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what modx is trying to do - take a peek at the source or in a browser inspector, if modx is trying to parse them your code will look like:

```
 template: '<a href=""><img src="" /></a>'
```

I don't know of any way to tell modx not to parse them, BUT if you include your script rather than inline modx will not parse it. i.e.

```
<script src="path-to-script" ></script>
```

Comment: Exactly right, inspecting the source showed that. That solution works perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this inline using a plugin and adding a space between the {{ and }} like { { and } }
The plugin is called Brakify and it removes the space after modx evolution parsed the content.

I use this with angular when an external script doesn't work.